# how to compare contents at every index of two arrays and return the matching index

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I need to compare two arrays and where values of one array exists in another I need to insert next position after match in another array. but in my code it is not doing anything.

here is my code:

```
arr=[]
result=['Alphabets','reveals','help','opinions','Allah']
words=['Alif-Laam-Meem','NNP','Alphabets','NNPS','of','IN','the','DT',' Arabic','NNP','language','NN','Allah','NNP','and','CC','to','TO', 'whomever','VB','He','PRP','reveals','VBZ','know','VBP','their','PRP','precise','JJ','meanings','NNS']
j=4
k=0
while j<len(words): #words contain text file contents that is split into words
    while k<len(result): #result is another array containing subsets of words of file.
         if result==words[j]: # if values of results match with values of words
             arr.append(words[j+1]) #add next index of words in arr.
             j+=1
             print(arr)
         else:
             continue
```

Comment: results is an empty list, it doesnt contain anything

Comment: An example with data is infinitely helpful.  Comparing the entire array `result` to an element of array `words`, but impossible to know without having an example of the data you're working with.

Comment: @N.Ivanov result is not empty..i need next index value of matched values  present in result

Comment: it was at the point when I posted the comment, seems like you have updated your answer

Comment: @N.Ivanov can you help me with the problem?

Comment: it is very unclear of what you are trying to achieve. Try to ask your question in a clear way. I dont understand anything from it. sorry

Comment: @N.Ivanov i want to match every value of result list with words list.if a match is found then i want to add that  value in a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> i want to match every value of result list with words list.if a match is found then i want to add that value in a new array.

There is a very simple way to do this. Here is a working example:

```
arr=[]
result=['Alphabets','reveals','help','opinions','Something']
words=['Alif-Laam-Meem','NNP','Alphabets','NNPS','of','IN','the','DT',' Arabic','NNP','language','NN','Something','NNP','and','CC','to','TO', 'whomever','VB','He','PRP','reveals','VBZ','know','VBP','their','PRP','precise','JJ','meanings','NNS']

for i in result:
    if i in words:
        arr.append(i)
print arr
```

This will give you:

`['Alphabest', 'reveals', 'Something']`

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is giving me an empty array.

Comment: @Nisa I just copy pasted it and ran it. Works without a problem. I am unsure how it is not working for you. I am using Python 2.7. Try and copy paste the solution and see if you have missed anything. Otherwise the program runs without problems.

Comment: can you help with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881148/how-to-match-elements-of-two-lists-and-access-their-indexes

Comment: @Nisa how about you sitdown, go over some tutorials, do some learning and solve it by yourself? SO is not a free coding service, nor a tutorial website.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment

> i want to match every value of result list with words list.if a match is found then i want to add that value in a new array.

Here is one more approach

```
result=['Alphabets','reveals','help','opinions','Something']
words=['Alif-Laam-Meem','NNP','Alphabets','NNPS','of','IN','the','DT',' Arabic','NNP','language','NN','Something','NNP','and','CC','to','TO', 'whomever','VB','He','PRP','reveals','VBZ','know','VBP','their','PRP','precise','JJ','meanings','NNS']

arr = [ word for word in result if word in words]
print(arr)
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, can you accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: can you help me with this problem ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881148/how-to-match-elements-of-two-lists-and-access-their-indexes