# how to match elements of two lists and access their indexes

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

i want to match elements from a list and append the next index after match in an array list but in my code it is giving me an empty array.I dont know where the problem is. in my code result is also an array containing a file named 'hilalitag.txt' split into words .but here for simplicity i mentioned result as an array with few values. I want to match elements of result with elements of words and if a match is found in words then i need to append the next index of words after match in an array named arr[].

```
sample_text='ahmedrazatg.txt'
lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
file = open(sample_text,'r')
arr=[]
result=[]
for line in file.readlines():
   words=re.split(' |/|:|;|,|-RRB-|-LRB-|!|\*|\*\*|``',line) #removing punctuations from file
   words=[line.replace(".","") for line in words] #removing full stop from file        
   i=4
   while i<len(words):            # this loop store words of a file in an array
      l=lemmatizer.lemmatize(words[i]) #array of words is lematized here
      i += 1
      result=['Alphabets','reveals','help','opinions','Allah'] 
      j=4
      for j in words:
         if j in result:
            arr.append(j+1)
      print(arr)
```

Comment: 1. Cut down the explanation 2. Less code, more examples 3. Some input and expected output would help

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need this :

```
arr = []
result=['Alphabets','reveals','help','opinions','Allah'] 
words=['Alphabets',"1",'reveals',"2",'help',"3",'opinions',"4",'Allah',"5"] 

for j in range(0, len(words)):
 if words[j] in result:
    arr.append(words[j+1])
print(arr)
```

If not please add some shorter code and `expected output` , that will help to understand